# Signup with Microsoft developer account

Tags: cordova, uwp, windows-store-apps, winjs, msdn

I want to publish UWP app to store. For this user must have sign-in with Microsoft developer account. I am trying to sign-up process from last 2 weeks but each time it throws an error

> Something went wrong and we can't sign you in right now. Please try
>   again later. The Microsoft account login server has detected too many
>   repeated authentication attempts. Please wait a moment and try again.

[image: Click here to see the screenshot]

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Also, what is there any limitation if select individual account for sign-up process. I want to publish app for limited users.

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to microsoft account support team ? Also,this question has nothing to do with programming..please move your question to appropriate portal..

Comment: Are you able to login to your outlook account and try to switch to old login page

Comment: @ShubhamSahu I dont have outlook account.

Comment: @Pratyay Yes I also posted the same question on microsoft forum but not received any reply. Thats why posted here.

Comment: @avinash can you create first a hotmail or outlook account and then try to signup again alternately you can also use DevShare app in the store but purchase your own developer dashboard is recommended

Answer (score 1):

> Please let me know if I am missing something.

Please see the step2 of **[The account signup process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/opening-a-developer-account#the-account-signup-process)**:

> **"2. If you're not already signed in with a Microsoft account, sign in
>   now, or create a new Microsoft account. The Microsoft account you use
>   here will be what you use to sign in to your developer account**."

You might firstly sign up for an outlook or hotmail account so that you can sign in Dev Center page correctly.

> what is there any limitation if select individual account for sign-up
>   process. I want to publish app for limited users.

Individual account may be restricted with certain app capabilities. But personally I think it can be enough for your use.

For more details, you can refer to [**Account types, location, and fee**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/account-types-locations-and-fees).

To publish app for limited users, you will have several beta testing options offered by Dev Center. You could select from them when create your Store submission according to your need.

You might check **[Beta testing and targeted distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution)**.

Comment: My application uses pictures library, music and camera access. Does these capabilities are allowed for personal account type?